# Can netty be used to server data to backbone on the front end?

Tags: java, backbone.js, real-time, netty

I know node.js is usually used to server as a backend to backbone.js, but can netty also do this?

I prefer the jvm, and was hoping someone could provide some production worthy code that serves as a backend to backbone.js.

**And the main point of this is to be able to have a real-time web application, so it would use long-polling to maintain a connection with the client to update the UI (say someone updated something via a mobile device, the browser should react to this).**

Comment: Wait, what code are you asking?

Comment: backend netty code to respond to client connections, keep alive long polling and updates being sent to backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone is 100% backend agnostic.

Our entire site is built on top of Backbone for the front-end and the backend is entirely in Java.

Personal projects have used Python and Flask to handle the API layer.

Backbone was originally culled from a RoR project...

Comment: do you use netty for long-polling to keep a constant connection to your backbone front end though? that is what I am interested in, for real time updates.

Comment: @user1361315 Use [socket.io](http://socket.io) my friend!  It's got backends in many languages including java.  What I like about Backbone is that it's very agnostic.  It does nothing for you in terms of socket communication, so use a library which works for you.  FYI - I know trello and possibly this site both use it.

Comment: which socket.io implementation did you use?

Comment: We don't use socket.io at work, but I have built demos on top of the node.js implementation and the gevent based Python implementation.